# I have a "TypeError: string indices must be integers" when running a Python crawler

Tags: python-3.x, web-crawler

Following a tutorial, I wrote this code for a crawler that retrieves search results about specific words from specific websites.
This is the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class Content:
    """Common base class for all articles/pages"""
    def __init__(self, topic, url, title, body):
        self.topic = topic
        self.url = url
        self.title = title
        self.body = body

    def print(self):
        """Flexible printing function controlling output"""
        print('New article found for topic: {}'.format(self.topic))
        print('URL: {}'.format(self.url))
        print('TITLE: {}'.format(self.title))
        print('BODY:\n{}'.format(self.body))

class Website:
    """Contains information about website structure"""
    def __init__(self, name, url, searchUrl, resultListing, resultUrl, absoluteUrl, titleTag, bodyTag):
        self.name = name
        self.url = url
        self.searchUrl = searchUrl
        self.resultListing = resultListing
        self.resultUrl = resultUrl
        self.absoluteUrl = absoluteUrl
        self.titleTag = titleTag
        self.bodyTag = bodyTag

class Crawler:
    def getPage(self, url):
        try:
            req = requests.get(url)
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
            return None
        return BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')

    def safeGet(self, pageObj, selector):
        childObj = pageObj.select(selector)
        if childObj is not None and len(childObj) > 0:
            return childObj[0].get_text()
        return ''

    def search(self, topic, site):
        """Searches a give website for a given topic and records all pages found"""
        bs = self.getPage(site.searchUrl + topic)
        searchResults = bs.select(site.resultListing)
        for result in searchResults:
            url = result.select(site.resultUrl)[0].attrs['href']
            #Check to see whether it' a relative or an absolute URL
            if(site.absoluteUrl):
                bs = self.getPage(url)
            else:
                bs = self.getPage(site.url + url)
            if bs is None:
                print('Something was wrong with that page or URL. Skipping!')
                return
            title = self.safeGet(bs, site.titleTag)
            body = self.safeGet(bs, site.bodyTag)
            if title != '' and body != '':
                content = Content(topic, title, body, url)
                content.print()

crawler = Crawler()

siteData = [
    ['Brookings', 'http://www.brookings.edu', 'https://www.brookings.edu/search/?s=',
        'div.list-content article', 'h4.title a', True, 'h1', 'div.post-body'],
--->['Corriere', 'http://www.corriere.it', 'https://sitesearch.corriere.it/forward.jsp?q=',
        'div#ris-ricerca', 'p.article a', True, 'h1', 'h2']
]

sites = []
for row in siteData:
    sites.append(Website(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row [5], row[6], row[7]))

topics = ['python', 'data science']
for topic in topics:
    print('GETTING INFO ABOUT: ' + topic)
    for targetSite in sites:
        crawler.search(topic, targetSite)
```

However, when I run it I get this error message:

```
File "crawlSearch.py", line 74, in <module>
    ['Corriere', 'http://www.corriere.it', 'https://sitesearch.corriere.it/forward.jsp?q=',
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I cannot understand why it only gives me the error for one website. Please, advise.

Comment: If you get the error from that line, then I suspect you have a typo in the previous line, not evident in the code you have posted.

Comment: I've tried running the code you posted and it works without exception. What version of Python are you using? Did you change anything in the code (like removing sensitive data) before posting it here?

Comment: Thank you, @frollo. I'm using python 3.7.4, and I haven't changed anything. However, it works for all the websites provided by the tutorial, but I cannot make it work when I try with a website I come up with.